# undirected graphs algorithms

Tags: algorithm, graph, nodes

Suppose that we have an n-node, m-edge undirected graph G = (V; E) and we have two distinct nodes
called s and t. Suppose that the distance between s and t is strictly greater than n/2
. Show that there
is a node v which is dierent from s and t such that every path from s to t goes through v. 
Give an algorithm with running time O(n + m) to nd such a vertex. You do not have to
prove that your algorithm is correct but you must give a proof that a vertex like v exists.

I can not figure out an exact answer to this past paper question, help me out!

Comment: The community standard is you show what you have done so far and not just ask for answers

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are two paths between s and t, that don't share a node. Since distance between s and t is > n/2, than each path has >= n/2 nodes between s and t. That means that graph has >= n+2 nodes, what is a contradiction.

For algorithm it is enough to find any path and than see where sub-graph that is connected to one side (s) without using path nodes finish. In more details:

- if s is connected only to one node than that node we are looking for.
- if not, make BFS from s
- find path s-t
- find nodes connected to s without using edges going from nodes of path s-t
- last node on path s-t that is in connected part is node we are looking for.

Comment: I may be misreading either the question, but it looks like the question asks to prove that there is a single node that every path shares, while you proved that for every pair of paths, they share at least 1 node (but not necessarily the same node).

Comment: Not exactly. This proves that it is not possible to find 2 paths that do not share at least one node. That means there exists (at least) one node which removal disconnects graph in (at least) 2 parts, and s and t are in different parts. Proof is not constructive, but existence. For constructive proof we need an algorithm :-)

Comment: Ah, I caught your logic now. I'd add that to your original answer, since as it stands, your proof seems incomplete.

Comment: I added algorithm, now it is complete :-)